# Add element in many to many field and preserve order

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
class Country(Models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('code', 'name'),)
        db_table = 'md_country'


class UserSettings(models.Model):
        ...
                                                  
        default_countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, db_table='user_default_countries', related_name='default_countries')
```

I have two models inside django models, what im trying is when i add Country models to default_countries i want to preserve order. Currently when i append manytomany field django automatically sort by Country name (alphabetical order)

I have this code

```
# iterate one by one to preserve fetching order
country_models = [Country.objects.get(id=_id) for _id in request.data[default_countries]]
user_settings.default_countries.clear()
for c in country_models:
    user_settings.default_countries.add(c)
```

After this when i inspect user_settings.default_countries i have ordered countries by name in alphabetical order.

I want to preserve when adding element. If i want to add France and Australia and i order the list like that i on the end when i pull data from db i want it to be ordered like that. Now on this example i have Australia then France.

**EDIT**:

I checked the database and when inserting the data, it insert in right order
[image]

For example if i want France(73) then Australia(13), France has smaller id so its inserted first. There is a problem with django when pulling the data from database.

Comment: What records order actually do you want?

Comment: I don't want to order it at all. So if for example i add
France then Australia. When i pull it out later i want the same order.
Now if i do FR then AU i will get Australia then France. Basically it ordered automatically by name (in alphabetical order). I want it to be like it is initially.

Comment: @Stefan Django should not be doing that unless you specified it somehow. Do you perhaps have `ordering = ['name']` in the `Meta` of your model `Country`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I dont have any ordering inside models scripts

Comment: Ah I see, I believe `request.data[default_countries]` is ordered by the country name. Django would not do any default ordering unless you specify it. In the snippet you show you yourself clear and add the instances to the m2m. Try `print([i for i in request.data[default_countries]])` what is the output?

Comment: I do this already, you can see the comment that im iterating one by one to preserve the order. 

Maybe there is a problem when django saves the default_countries manytomany field. Infact im adding it in right order but when django generate sqls maybe i have different order then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround.

Firstly i defined new property inside model where default_countries is.

```
@property
def ordered_default_countries(self):
    return self.default_countries.all().order_by('-id')
```

Then in serializer where i serialize this field i just pointed **default_countries** field to **ordered_default_countries**.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand correct you want to sort by insert order:

```
someSetting = UserSettings.objects.first()
countries = someSetting.default_countries.order_by('id')
```

Comment: Yes, basaically this is workound which may work